# Tag system recommendation questions with the systems that get recommended?

Tags: discussion, game-recommendation

Just a thought to make the site perhaps more useful to future users who search, could we make it standard practice to edit system-recommendation questions (the good ones, I mean) to include tags for the systems that wind up getting recommended? The accepted answer’s recommendations, perhaps, or maybe all of them with (greater than some number? positive? non-negative?) ratings.

Anyway, what do people think?

Comment: You do realize search operates on all words in the body of the answers too right?

Comment: @mxyzplk: I do, but people also use tags in searches, or click on the tag itself. Tags have a purpose, or we wouldn't use any.

Answer (score 13):

Sounds good at first but the devil's in the details.

1. There's a limited number of tags allowed on a question. So tagging with all systems won't work.
2. The "best answer" doesn't necessarily have just one system in it, and may not have been accepted because they're all good. So the minimum viable "let's tag with the winner" isn't even necessarily correct.
3. Top voted answers will change over time - including over a very long amount of time.  Tagging off these will require maintenance and potentially generate argument from boosters of various answers.
4. Tagging in this way fails to describe the questions, which is the avowed purpose of tags.  If I want to find questions about Ars Magica, a question that just recommends it to some guy is of super limited utility.

As a result of meditating upon these truths I think that no, tagging system-recs with answer systems is not a best practice.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize the limit on tags, and your other points are very good. OK then.

Comment: I think the kicker is that tags are supposed to describe the *question* not the answers.  Just because an answer has "Ars Magica" doesn't make it an "Ars Magica" question.  If you want any references to a game, the search already supports that.